# Rails retrieving from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm using Rails and in a controller, I have a database called log_cons and it has an entry all filled in whereby the first column is "id" and the value is "1"

```
@log_cons = LogCon.all
puts @log_cons[1].id
```

This outputs to the browser:

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

and prints an empty line in the terminal.

What could be some potential reasons for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LogCon.find()` will return an `ActiveRecord` object, not an array.

Thus you can just get the id like so:

```
@log_cons = LogCon.all
puts @log_cons[0].id
```

or

```
puts @log_cons.first.id
```

Comment: Oh, I am trying to get an array of all the records. How would I do that, and print the id for each?

Comment: `LogCon.all` will return all the objects, then you can just loop through each of the elements like so `LogCon.all.each { |o| puts o.id }`

Comment: You can also do `@log_cons.first.id`

Comment: I agree with Luís, using `first` is much more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all records, do

```
@log_cons = LogCon.all
```

and then access the first one doing

```
puts @log_cons[0].id
```

Comment: `@log_cons[0].id` is the first result.

Comment: If you are searching for the first object inside that array, your index has to be zero, not one - i.e. `puts @log_cons[0].id` instead of `puts @log_cons[1].id`